# Occasional screen blackouts on Debian 7

Tags: debian, video, graphic-card

I installed Debian 7 on an Asus Eee PC 2101HA.

Sometimes the screen goes black for 1 second.

My VGA card is `VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation System Controller Hub (SCH Poulsbo) Graphics Controller (rev 07)`

Comment: If I have to guess it could be either someone making fun of you or the cable is damaged.

Comment: @Braiam I suspect OP means the built-in display. Which means its probably not a bad cable, unless OP has been disassembling the laptop.

Comment: Note to anyone looking at this in the re-open queue: The Intel video driver, chipsets, or the displays attached to them are (or were) known to have bugs like this—much of this is fixed in newer kernels. This question isn't nearly as opaque as it at first appears (for details, see my answer, or ask Google about *i915 screen flicker* or similar).

Comment: @derobert - you're assuming that one would characterize goes black for 1 second and flicker as being the same, which I wouldn't have thought of as being the same.

Comment: I agree, it's not what you'd normally think of as monitor flicker, which is something that only existed on CRTs. But really, its fairly similar—the screen goes dark, then bright again. Just this is a much lower frequency than the 60Hz refresh flicker. Of course, if it were obvious that "flicker" is the right word to plop into Google, you'd not really need to ask here.

Comment: @derobert - point taken, voted to reopen BTW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several Intel drivers options which, if they don't work perfectly with your hardware, can cause issues like this:

- The big one is `lvds_downclock`, but it defaults to off. If you've changed that default, that's the first one to try. (It's possible some kernel versions defaulted to on, so its worth a try to force-disable it).
- `i915_enable_fbc` can cause various display issues. The default is per-chip, you may want to try turning it off.

Both of the above will probably increase power usage a little.

- Finally, `powersave` defaults to true, turning it off will disable a bunch of powersaving stuff at once. This will probably work, but you'll notice the battery life hit.

There are two ways to set these values:

1. On the kernel command line, like this: `i915.i915_enable_fbc=0`. Yes, you need the `i915.` prefix, even when the option name starts with i915. You can test temporarily by editing the command line in GRUB before booting, and set permanently in the grub config (edit `/etc/default/grub`, then run `update-grub`. Or `dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc`).
2. Create a new file in `/etc/modprobe.d`, for example `/etc/modprobe.d/local-i915.conf`. Then inside it, put `options i915 i915_enable_fbc=0 lvds_downclock=0` (etc.). Note that you do not use the `i915.` prefix here. After editing, run `update-initramfs -u`.

Another option is to try a newer kernel. Currently, [Debian Backports](http://backports.debian.org/) has 3.12. Newer kernels have fixed a lot of bugs in the Intel video driver, and also have better knowledge of when which hardware particular powersaving features work on.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried this way and it's seems good. Now the black screens comes very rarely, but sometimes they come back. There are some other drivers to add to black list?!

Comment: @BauMiao I don't think there are any drivers to blacklist, it's not like nVidia or ATI where there are both open and proprietary drivers. I'd suggest either trying a newer kernel or check `modinfo i915` to see other parameters you can tweak.

Comment: @BauMiao e.g., I'd try Linux 3.12 from https://backports.debian.org/

Comment: Thanks again. Your reply is extremely clear! I will try with a new kernel...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a common problem with Linux and Intel chipsets. If you have i915 chipsets and Grub, try editing `/etc/default/grub` and adding `i915.enable_psr=0` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line. E.g., `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="foo bar i915.enable_psr=0"`. Then run command `update-grub` and reboot.

Comment: Rather: `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`